# How to divide a vector by a scalar in R and plot it

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm making some histograms of a Bernoulli Experiment of 2000 iterations. I got a lot of 0's and 1's, so I plot the result and got a nice histogram with frequencies from 0 to 1000. Now i have to divide the frequencies by 2000 and plot again, but how do I do it?

I've tried to got the vectors of the values and the frequencies individuality, but in the end I don't know how to put the values on the x-axis and the new frequencies on the y-axis.

```
Bernoulli = function(p){
  x = runif(1)
  if(x <= p){
    0
  }
  else{
    1
  }
}

Experiment = function(){
  vec = c(1,2000)
  for(i in 1:2000){
    vec[i] = Bernoulli(0.5)
  }
  vec
}

x = Experiment()

graph1 = hist(x, main="Bernoulli Experiment",
     xlab = "Value",
     ylab = "Frequence",
     col = "red",
     xlim = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to plot your data on a 0 to 1 scale.  Use this:

```
plot(table(x)/2000)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0.2,0.8,0.2)) # add x-axis ticks from 0.2 to 0.8 by 0.2 increments
```